# React child class receiving undefined props even if class is mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to send an object as 'props' from a parent Class into a Child class with the intention of showing information:

**Parent class**

```
const TaskDetail = () => {

    //Get parameter from URL
    const { id } = useParams()

    const [taskDetail, setTaskDetail] = useState([])


    useEffect(() => {
        TaskService.getTaskById(id)
            .then(response => {
                setTaskDetail(response.data);
            })

    }, [id]) //This [id] avoid infinite loop of requests
    
    if (!taskDetail) return <div>No data</div>

    return (
        <div>
            <Detail taskDetail={taskDetail}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This class makes a request to the server and gather a data object. This object is then passed onto the Child Detail where it will be deserialized and visualized accordingly.

**Child class**

```
const Detail = ({ taskDetail }) => {


    return (
        <Box
            align='center'
            justifyContent='center'
            sx={{ width: '100%', marginTop: 4}}
            bgcolor=''
            //border='solid'
            >
            <Stack
                //border='solid'
                sx = {{width: '50%'}}
                justifyContent='center' 
                //border='solid'
                >
                <Typography
                    sx = {{ marginTop: 5}}
                    variant='h4'
                    fontWeight='bold'
                    bgcolor='#b2dafa'  
                    >NOMBRE DEL EJERCICIO<br/>{taskDetail.taskName}</Typography>
                    <Box
                        sx = {{ marginTop: 3}}
                        bgcolor='#b2dafa'
                    >
                        <Typography
                            variant='h5'
                            align='center'
                            sx = {{ margin: 2}}
                            fontWeight='bold'  
                            >DETALLES DEL EJERCICIO</Typography>
                        <Typography
                            sx = {{ margin: 2}}
                            variant='text'
                            border='#555'
                            >{taskDetail.details}
                            </Typography>
                    </Box>
                    <Box
                        sx = {{ marginTop: 5}}>
                    <Typography
                            variant='h6'
                            >Marca para completar</Typography><Toogle
                            label=''
                            toogled={false}
                            onClick={null}/>
                        <br></br>
                    </Box>
                    {taskDetail.id}
                    <Box
                        sx = {{ marginTop: 2}}>
                        <AddComment taskId={taskDetail.id}/>
                    </Box>
                    <Box
                        sx = {{ marginTop: 2}}>
                        <ListComments taskId={taskDetail.id}/>
                    </Box>
            </Stack>   
        </Box>
    )
}
```

As you can observe, this object is also passed to other child components. The context is that TaskDetail shows information and then offers two features, ListComments and AddComments. At the current moment, I am having an issue in AddComment where the prop `taskId={taskDetail.id}` is undefined.

**Function in Child where I am having this issue**

```
function ListComments(props) {

    const [comments, setComments] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
    
        console.log('DEBUG listcomments: ' + props.taskId)
        TaskService.getTaskCommentsById(props.taskId)
            .then(response => {
                setComments(response.data)
            })
        
    }, [])

return (
        <div>
            <h2>Comentarios</h2>
            {comments.map((comment, _) => {    
                return  <Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment}/>
            })}
        </div>
)


}
```

I have noticed, that if I change something in the code and save it (re-renders the page). All of a sudden I get the atribute that I need instead of the undefined value.

**How could I avoid this situation?**
I trust that I have made a huge mistake that I am unable to see, but its part of the learning. For this reason, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data you get back from the service is an object I would suggest to initialize the state with an object `{}`.

```js
const [taskDetail, setTaskDetail] = useState({});
```

In the `ListComments` component you can do the same as you did in the `TaskDetail` component. Run `useEffect` when the `props.taskId` changes. And add a early return if the `taskId` have no value yet.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("DEBUG listcomments: " + props.taskId);

  if (!props.taskId) return;

  TaskService.getTaskCommentsById(props.taskId).then((response) => {
    setComments(response.data);
  });
}, [props.taskId]);
```

Comment: I would like to let you know that I tried your suggestiong and it works. Perhaps I can "return" inside the UseEffect if the props was not loaded forcing the component to re-render or fetch it again in a loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very cool that you're reaching out for help!

First, just a minor correction: They're not classes, they're functions / components.

I think the problem is the check condition at the top:

`if (!taskDetail) return <div>No data</div>`

Since taskDetail is initialised as an array, the condition will always be true since arrays are objects in javascript.

Because of this too, when you're passing it down, at least on the first render, none of these props in the lower components exist. So maybe try initalising it either as `null`, or changing the condition to the following:

`if (!taskDetail || taskDetail.length === 0) return <div>No data</div>`

One more thing, to make sure that the data is fetched, you need to add `props.taskId` to the dependency list in the List component.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words!, I just have one month full learning Javascript and React for fun. You are totally right about the array check, I changed it and its works, but regarding the props dependency, I do not quite understand what does it mean.